# How do I find a way to create a global single.php for a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, single

I am working on making a custom post type plugin for my website. However, I want to make it universal for any theme I may decide to change. Or to be able to append the post type to a single post file already.

It's a press release post type, and I am unable to find any guide to how to append or create a universal template file for the single post file.

Any guides or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There re various filters you can use to inject your custom template. One being the [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include), the other [`single_template`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template), and even [`type_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/).

The easiest one would be `single_template` in your case (example from codex):

```
function get_custom_post_type_template($single_template) {
     global $post;

     if ($post->post_type == 'my_post_type') {
          $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/post-type-template.php';
     }
     return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_custom_post_type_template' );
```

Comment: I have that part already. I am trying to find a basic 'single.php' that would work with any theme or how to add the parts I am needing for the post to appear on any 'single.php' before the content and after the content.

Comment: I wonder if it's better to use `template_include` or `type_template`. What are the pros and cons